# typo3 fluid based backend extension file upload controller code

Tags: file-upload, typo3, backend

i am creating typo3 extension development.In that we have file upload i am confused regarding the directory of upload and code to be written in the controller.i know the form code of fluid i.e. but controller code i have no idea.so seeking help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to do it the proper way, you should use FAL for file uploads instead of handling it yourself completely. There is an elaborate post about FAL upload with Extbase by Helmut Hummel, to be found [here](http://insight.helhum.io/post/85015526410/file-upload-using-extbase-and-fal-in-typo3-6-2).

Helmut also provided a demo extension as a proof of concept, to be found on [Github](https://github.com/helhum/upload_example).

Answer (score -3):

The example from Helmut Hummel works for Typo3 6.2 but not for 8.x and higher. Cause of removed methods calls like **getValue(false)** in his own UploadViewHelper.

A other way, without a own FileReference, is to upload a file with using the FileAbstractionLayer is the following.

Frontend:
Create a form for your model class.
Note: The form need the attributes **method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data"**

```
<f:form action="addDownloadItem" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" object="{newDownloadItem}" name="newDownloadItem">
    <input type="file" property="file" name="datei">
</f:form>
```

In your controller action write the following code:

```
    public function addDownloadItemAction(DownloadItem $newDownloadItem, SubCategory $subCategory){

        $file = $_FILES['datei'];

        $storage = $this->storageRepository->findAll()[0];
        $fileObject = $storage->addFile($file['tmp_name'], $storage->getDefaultFolder(), $file['name']);
        $fileObject = $storage->getFile($fileObject->getIdentifier());

        $this->downloadItemRepository->add($newDownloadItem);

        $fileResourceReference = new \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Resource\FileReference(array('uid_local' => $fileObject->getUid()));

        /** @var \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Domain\Model\FileReference $fileSysReference */
        $fileSysReference = $this->objectManager->get(\TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Domain\Model\FileReference::class);
        $fileSysReference->setOriginalResource($fileResourceReference);
        $fileSysReference->setPid($this->storagePid);

        $newDownloadItem->setFile($fileSysReference);

        $subCategory->addDownloadItem($newDownloadItem);

        $this->subCategoryRepository->add($subCategory);

}
```

Now let us have a look at the model class:

```
class DownloadItem extends \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\DomainObject\AbstractEntity {

/**
 * file
 *
 * @var \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Domain\Model\FileReference
 */
protected $file = NULL;

...
```

The TCA should look like the following:

```
'file' => array(
        'exclude' => 1,
        'label' => 'LLL:EXT:<<extKey>>/Resources/Private/Language/locallang_db.xlf:tx_<<extKey>>_domain_model_downloaditem.file',
        'config' => \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\ExtensionManagementUtility::getFileFieldTCAConfig(
            'file',
            array('maxitems' => 1,
                'appearance' => array(
                    'createNewRelationLinkTitle' => 'LLL:EXT:cms/locallang_ttc.xlf:media.addFileReference'
                ),
                'foreign_types' => array(
                    '0' => array(
                        'showitem' => '
                        --palette--;LLL:EXT:lang/locallang_tca.xlf:sys_file_reference.imageoverlayPalette;imageoverlayPalette,
                        --palette--;;filePalette'
                    ),
                    \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Resource\File::FILETYPE_TEXT => array(
                        'showitem' => '
                        --palette--;LLL:EXT:lang/locallang_tca.xlf:sys_file_reference.imageoverlayPalette;imageoverlayPalette,
                        --palette--;;filePalette'
                    ),
                    \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Resource\File::FILETYPE_IMAGE => array(
                        'showitem' => '
                        --palette--;LLL:EXT:lang/locallang_tca.xlf:sys_file_reference.imageoverlayPalette;imageoverlayPalette,
                        --palette--;;filePalette'
                    ),
                    \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Resource\File::FILETYPE_AUDIO => array(
                        'showitem' => '
                        --palette--;LLL:EXT:lang/locallang_tca.xlf:sys_file_reference.imageoverlayPalette;imageoverlayPalette,
                        --palette--;;filePalette'
                    ),
                    \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Resource\File::FILETYPE_VIDEO => array(
                        'showitem' => '
                        --palette--;LLL:EXT:lang/locallang_tca.xlf:sys_file_reference.imageoverlayPalette;imageoverlayPalette,
                        --palette--;;filePalette'
                    ),
                    \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Resource\File::FILETYPE_APPLICATION => array(
                        'showitem' => '
                        --palette--;LLL:EXT:lang/locallang_tca.xlf:sys_file_reference.imageoverlayPalette;imageoverlayPalette,
                        --palette--;;filePalette'
                    )
                ),
                'foreign_match_fields' => array(
                    'tablenames' => 'tx_<<extKey>>_domain_model_downloaditem',
                ),
        )
    ),
),
```

**Note:** you can change the file types **foreign_types**, but the important part is:

```
'foreign_match_fields' => array(
                'tablenames' => 'tx_<<extKey>>_domain_model_downloaditem',
            ),
```

The tablenames have to be the name of your model table.

**Notes:**

1. Now you have saved the file in the default Folder.
   If you want a other folder, change the argument $storage->getDefaultFolder() to your own.
2. If you want to create a download link for the file in the frontend use: {downloadItem.file.originalResource.publicUrl} in the href of the  tag

Comment: Don't know who removed my previous comment, but here we go again. This answer still isn't 100% correct. *Cause of removed methods calls like getValue(false) in his own FileReference* The method was never called in the FileReference object, but in the UploadViewHelper. For TYPO3 7.6 and higher the own FileReference object can indeed be omitted, but it on the other hand also does not harm.

Comment: Besides that, the whole point of creating the upload_example was to teach people to separate concerns and **not** do property mapping stuff (handling file uploads) in the controller, but to use the property mapping infrastructure for that (see link to blog post in accepted answer).

Comment: I have done some changed in the Code. Please do Not downvote my example until you have tested it. I have wrote a issue in your repository, but you have not answered until now. Your example currently dosn't work with typo 8.x thats the Point i've written this example

Comment: I don't think your code is a good solution, that is why I down voted it. Please deal with it. Meanwhile I updated the upload_example to work with TYPO3 8.x, so maybe you may want to give this another try. If not and you are more happy with your code, fine with me as well. I won't use or recommend it anyway ;)